# Set X-XSS-Protection header in Rails 3.2.8 - Rails is lowercasing the header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, http-headers

I'm trying to set the X-XSS-Protection header to "0" in Rails 3.2.8 to prevent Internet Explorer from throwing XSS errors.  See more details about the header in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090577/what-is-the-http-header-x-xss-protection/10369475#10369475) and [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/01/31/controlling-the-internet-explorer-xss-filter-with-the-x-xss-protection-http-header.aspx). I'm currently using this in my application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_headers

  def set_headers
    response.headers['X-XSS-Protection'] = "0"
  end
end
```

In development, this sets the header just fine. `curl -i http://localhost:3000` returns:

```
X-XSS-Protection: 0
```

But in production, (`curl -i http://production-app.com`) the header is improperly lowercased, and IE seems to ignore it.

```
X-Xss-Protection: 0
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?