# Avoiding HTML-escape in XSS

Tags: security, xss

I have written in a tiny node.js server for testing purposes:

```
require('http').createServer(function(req,res){ 
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/html"}); 
    res.end(req.url); 
}).listen(8888);
```

The idea is that the url:

```
http://localhost:8888/Guest
```

will output

"/Guest".

Numerous tutorials I have seen suggests that the URL:

```
http://localhost:8888/<script>alert("XSS");</script>
```

should perform XSS. Instead, I receive the URL-encoded output:

```
/%3Cscript%3Ealert(%22XSS%22);%3C/script%3E
```

Why is this? My server clearly has dozens of vulnerabilities, what am I missing?

Comment: How do you send the request? It’s probably your web client that encode the URL as some characters are required to be encoded (i. e., `<` and `>`).

Comment: Figured, tests with telnet return the < back. My question really should be: how do the real attacks avoid the victim's browser escaping the tags?

Comment: Perhaps you are using IE? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10369475/81179

Comment: Have you tried it as a link rather than directly into the address bar? i.e. `<a href ="http://localhost:8888/&lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;XSS&quot;);&lt;/script&gt;">Click</a>`