# Cross origin requests are only supported

Tags: javascript, css, cross-domain

When I click the link in the code bellow:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<div id="modal_open" class="modal fade" role="document">
    <div class="modal-dialog custom-modal-size">
        <div class="modal-content">
            text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_open" ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">link</a>
```

I get a `jquery.min.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load javascript:void(0);. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.` message if I have open the chrome debugger. While the code works as expected, I am trying to understand why I get this message. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Please show the entire error message.

Comment: @Lambda Ninja OK, updated.

Comment: Retry after setting up HTTP XSS Header. To know more : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090577/what-is-the-http-header-x-xss-protection

Comment: @Hari Harker Thanks for teh help! I added the following PHP line: `header("X-XSS-Protection: 0");` but I still get the error.

Comment: _“XMLHttpRequest cannot load javascript:void(0)”_ – your script/system thinks that `javascript:void(0)` is an actual URL it should load via an AJAX request, which makes no sense whatsoever of course. Question is, what is that doing there in the first place?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your link tag you have `href="javascript:void(0);"` which is throwing the error. If you remove that, the error is gone.

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<div id="modal_open" class="modal fade" role="document">
    <div class="modal-dialog custom-modal-size">
        <div class="modal-content">
            text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_open" ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">link</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! What I should put in place of `javascript:void(0);` ?

Comment: I just posted what it does without it. Is there something else you're wanting it to do?

Comment: The problem with this solution is that if you need tabbing into the link (accessibility standards call for this) then removing the `href` attribute breaks that. I would suggest using `href="#"` and following @irfandar's answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can set href to # and onclick to `event.preventDefault(`) or `return false` to achieve same thing like this

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_open" ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">link</a>
```

OR

```
<a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_open" ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">link</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

> href="javascript:void(0);"

is causing it

Comment: Sry didn't see someone already posted the correct answer. It didnt get accepted. for shame.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use Chrome and opened the html-script from your filesystem?

Firefox or a webserver shoud fix this cross origin Problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am running this on localhost.